# How to remove whole JSON objects?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a JSON file that's thousands of lines but here is a short example of that file.

```
{
    "dataset_id": "??",
    "areas": [
         {
             "boundary_id": "76",
             "metric": 1.9,
             "data": {
                  "Economic_risk": "1.9",
                  "Housing_risk": "3.0"
                     }
         },
         { 
             "boundary_id": "76",
             "metric": NaN,
             "data": {
                  "Economic_risk": "",
                  "Housing_risk": ""
                     }
         }
]
}
```

My goal is to remove every part of the dataset that has a metric of NaN meaning the risk is "". Right now I am doing this but that doesn't get rid of everything.

```
import json

with open(test.json) as file:
    data = json.load(file)

    for area in data["areas"]:
        if area["data"]["Economic_risk] == "":
             del area["boundary_id"]
             del area["metric"]
             del area["data"]["Economic_risk"]
             del area["data"]["Housing_risk"]
             del area["data"]
with open("test_new.json", "w") as file:
      json.dump(data, file)
```

This gives me

```
   {
        "dataset_id": "??",
        "areas": [
             {
                 "boundary_id": "76",
                 "metric": 1.9,
                 "data": {
                      "Economic_risk": "1.9",
                      "Housing_risk": "3.0"
                         }
             },
             { 

             }
    ]
    }
```

however my desired output is something like this

```
{
    "dataset_id": "??",
    "areas": [
         {
             "boundary_id": "76",
             "metric": 1.9,
             "data": {
                  "Economic_risk": "1.9",
                  "Housing_risk": "3.0"
                     }
         }
         
]
```

}

can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you would need to delete the reference to that dictionary object in the areas list. So something like `del areas[1]`

Comment: Use pandas for this. It is performant + you will get one liner code for this

Comment: @DavidYue well, don't modify as you are iterating over it.

Comment: @tbhaxor it's pretty trivial to implement this in pure python. Getting a "one liner" is a pretty terrible reason to do things, but if you want, you can do this with a "one liner" as well

Comment: Anyway, you can just do something like `data['areas'] = [a for a in data['areas'] if a["data"]["Economic_risk] != ""]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is you are simply clearing the dict with multiple `del area[key]` statements... But that doesn't remove the dict from that list. Instead, just filter it out using the condition:

```
import json

with open(test.json) as file:
    data = json.load(file)

data['areas'] = [a for a in data['areas'] if a["data"]["Economic_risk"]]

with open("test_new.json", "w") as file:
      json.dump(data, file)
```